# Use source control history with nDepend to create trend

Tags: version-control, ndepend

***We would like to pick points in time in our source control (git) to generate trend metrics.***

We are working through a trial of nDepend to determine its value for our large, 15+ -year-old code base.

The steps taken so far are:

1. Checkout a given changeset
2. Build/analyze
3. Go to 1 until all selected changesets have been analyzed

The problem that we're seeing is that each time the code is checked out, it is a fresh start, including the nDepend configuration. As a result, we have a series of analytics sets that are completely independent, no trend across them.

Is this something that can (easily) be done?

Answer (score 1):

I've worked out a solution:

1. Update NDepend settings to attach NDepend projects to the .suo file
2. Update NDepend settings to have trend metrics logged "Always"
3. Checkout the initial changeset: git checkout {changesethash}
4. Buildthe solution
5. Attach new NDepend project to the current solution
6. Run analysis for the new NDepend project
7. Move the NDepend project file and the NDependOut folder to the solution's .vs folder
8. Edit the NDepend project file, adjusting the path of the .sln file from "." to ".."

At this point, repeat the following for each changeset for which you want to capture analytics:

1. Checkout the next changeset: git checkout {changesethash}
2. Build the solution
3. Run NDepend analysis

Hopefully I haven't missed anything.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you can automate most of these steps with [NDepend.API](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/ndepend-api-quickstart). You don't need to attach the NDepend project to the sln during automation, just use the method [SetIDEFile()](https://www.ndepend.com/api/webframe.html#NDepend.API%7ENDepend.Project.IProjectCodeToAnalyze%7ESetIDEFiles.html) to reference your solution(s) from the NDepend project:

```
var ndependServicesProvider = new NDependServicesProvider();
var projectManager = ndependServicesProvider.ProjectManager;
project.CodeToAnalyze.SetIDEFiles(new [] { new 
   IDEFile("C:\File.sln".ToAbsoluteFilePath()","-test") } );
IAnalysisResult analysisResult = project.RunAnalysis();
```

To aggregate the trend metrics you can use the [NDepend.Trend](https://www.ndepend.com/api/webframe.html#NDepend.API%7ENDepend.Trend_namespace.html) namespace and get inspiration from the [trend related OSS power tools](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/ndepend-oss-power-tools): **Dated log trend values**

Comment: Interesting! To be sure, are you saying that I would create a standalone program that runs the code that you provided independent of Visual Studio IDE?

Comment: Yes absolutely, please read the link about NDepend.API that explains it all